# Paginate in CakePHP with sum of multiple rows from specific column of another model

Tags: sql, cakephp, pagination

Sorry for the question title. English is not my primary language and I can't figure out how to express the trouble I'm having.

I have these two tables:

- Visits
- Sellouts

**The relation is**: Each visit have multiple sellouts

How to create a $paginate on CakePHP adding the SUM of all rows in SELLOUTS relative to each VISIT?

So:

## **Pagination result expected**

```
 ____________________________
| ID | VISIT_DATE | SELLOUTS |
 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  1 |    11/2    |   200    |
|____|____________|__________|
```

Where the ammount of "200" sellouts is the SUM of RELATIVE ROWS in **Sellouts** table:

## **Sellouts Table**

```
 _________________________
| ID | VISIT_ID |  VALUE  |
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  1 |     1    |   50    |
|  2 |     1    |   50    |
|  3 |     1    |   50    |
|  4 |     1    |   50    |
|____|__________|_________|
```

Comment: have you taken a look at out virtual fields can help your situation?

Comment: YOU JUST SAVED MY DAY :D

Many many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As @ayo-akinyemi said. Virtual Fields do the job.

Just have created at my **Visits** model a Virtual Field:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
        "sellouts" => "SELECT SUM(value) AS sellouts FROM Sellouts WHERE Visits.id = Sellouts.visit_id"
    );
```

and then, in my view I can access this field using

```
$paginator['Visit']['sellouts']
```